# Specific Fraction align center

Tags: css-grid

I have a complex layout to replicate with css grid. If you see it in full screen the "Top Banners" div is set to be max-width of 1200px and margin left and right to auto to be aligned center.

In the grid i have set 5 fractions. the last column fraction has to be 330px. The main_container has to be with max-width of 1200px and also aligned center. The rest of the column fractions should take the rest of the space. The sidebar fraction should be always stacked to the right.

The problem is that the top banners and the main content are not equal aligned center. I belive the Top Banners has the correct alignment. Here is what i did. Can anyone guide me how to achive the correct layout? Thanks.

Here is how it looks
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9kPl.jpg)

And here is what i did. Can anyone guide me how to achieve the correct layout? Thanks.

```css
html,
body,
.grid-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

/* **GRID LAYOUT** */
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) 330px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, max-content);
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

header.top_banners {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background-color: beige;
}

header.top_menu {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.skin_left {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

main.main_container {
  grid-column: 2/5;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
section.section_main_top_articles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  column-gap: 1.8rem;
}

.top_articles_image {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.top_articles_articles {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

aside.sidebar {
  grid-column: 5/-1;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}
footer {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background-color: darkorange;
}

/* **TOP BANNERS** */
.top_banners_container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sigmalive - Home</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,400;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <header class="top_banners">
        <div class="top_banners_container">Top Banners</div>
      </header>
      <header class="top_menu">Top Menu</header>
      <div class="skin_left">Skin Left</div>
      <main class="main_container">
        <section class="section_main_top_articles">
          <div class="top_articles_image">Main Top Articles Image</div>
          <div class="top_articles_articles">Main Top Articles Articles</div>
        </section>
      </main>
      <aside class="sidebar">Sidebar</aside>
      <footer>
        Footer
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `max-width` inside of a block like `1fr` (the relative width) - is very very wrong and will tear the grid. And how is it even possible to set the right sidebar with static width and expecting the center block to be correct in the center?

Comment: Maybe `grid-column: 2/5;` to the header ? the header is centered with margin auto within it's grid area which is 5 columns which would make it difficult to deduce where exactly it stands, The `main_container` however is spanning columns from 2 to 5, If you want them to align put both of them in the same column `grid-column: 2/5;`.

Comment: @focus.style. Thanks for your answer. That's why i am asking, because i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Zohir Salak. Thanks for your answer. The first two divs i can do them flex and remove them from the grid. Basically i want inside the grid one div which will be the main content and has max width of 1200px and is aligned center of the page always and another div which will be the sidebar and has width of 330px but is always stack on the right.

The layout i try to achieve is from this site https://www.sigmalive.com/.